# How can I fix the task scheduler error 0x00041303 or 0x41303?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a task scheduler in the task scheduler but it does not execute. in the column last run results aparace the following information: 0x41303.

Note: I already searched a lot and could not get any answers

Answer (score 1):

All the Task Scheduler error codes are define in the 'winerror.h' file, which is available as part of the Windows SDK. With regards to code 0x41303, the definition is:

```
SCHED_S_TASK_HAS_NOT_RUN         0x00041303
// The task has not yet run.
```

An easy way to lookup these codes is via web site http://errorco.de/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by changing the conditions of triggering. Initially I had it triggering only if a specific network connection was available. Then I changed the condition to "Any connection" and then the task started working.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the task in your Task Scheduler to open up its properties.  Click the History tab.  You should have more information here.

For me, it was "Launch Failure" with Error Value: 2147943785. Basically it means it cannot run a batch file unless I'm logged on.  Choosing "Run only when user is logged on" option solved the problem for me.

Comment: Convert decimal code 2147943785 to its hex value of 0x80070569 ans then lookup at http://errorco.de/  which shows this error to be ERROR_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. This problem usually occurred due to the default setting of the scheduler. By default the task is going to run only when AC power is enable for the system so if the laptop is on charging mode then only the task will start.
So You can try this solution by unchecking that checkbox.

[image: Task Scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

To convert nwsmith's comment into an answer:

The reason may be that the task's user does not have the "Log on as a batch job" privilege.

Usually the management console adds this privilege automatically to the user, but in a domain setting this may not be allowed due to the domain policy.

So, your options include:

- Try the Local Security Policy applet, "Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as batch job" and add your user, if this is allowed.
- Edit the domain policy so that your user has the privilege
- Use another user who already has the privilege
- Add your preferred user to a group which has the privilege assigned, in my setting this was "Backup Operators"

Answer (score 0):

Add a second trigger, "At task creation/modification". This starts the task after creation/modification, and therefore clears the "The task has not yet run. (0x41303)" state. A third trigger "At system start" with a delay of five minutes can be added as another fallback, but usually not needed.